# Temporary object: Clarification in terminology

Tags: c++, object, variables, assembly

When a function is called, unless optimizations are used by the compiler, a temporary object is returned.
There are 2 places where a temporary object can be created:
1) Stack
2) CPU REGISTERS
.
The terminology object in computer science indicates in fact a variable, a memory location, which includes all the instance variables whose definition occurred within the class from which the object was then created.
And here I ask my question:
CPU REGISTERS are variables inside the processor, which therefore are not found at the RAM level.
When I use an expression like: "The temporary object was created inside a CPU register", do I mean to say that the register is acting as a temporary object, or that the object is created in the register?

Being a CPU register, a variable, it should contain values, thus acting as a temporary object.
Clarify my ideas.

Comment: What exactly is your question? *"object ... indicates in fact a variable, a memory location"* The standard defines what a temporary object is, but it doesn't specify where those are stored. The object in a register is still an object.

Comment: An object is a variable, a cpu register is a variable too.
So is cpu register a temporary object ?

Does the concept of Object refers to a variable that contains different values, or refears to the values containend in the variable ?

Comment: A register is not a variable, but it can contain one. You can find the definitions you're looking for [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object). Roughly, any instance of a class or of a different type (except references) is an 'object'. A 'variable' is a named object or reference. 'Value' is one of the properties of an object.

Comment: but it is a sequence of bytes that are written in the same way as variables in main memory, only that the individual bytes do not have an address.

Comment: That's right, and...?

Comment: I am saying that if a register is a sequence of bytes, these bytes will be written.
So more than saying that a temporary object is created in a CPU register, being an object a variable, wouldn't it be more correct to say that it is the content of the object to be written in the CPU register?

Comment: I don't see any difference between saying "storing object in a register" and "storing object's content (more commonly called representation) in a register".

Answer (score 2):

> When I use an expression like: "The temporary object was created inside a CPU register", do I mean to say that the register is acting as a temporary object, or that the object is created in the register?

This seems like a fairly meaningless distinction, though the second phrasing is clearest and most idiomatic.

But I wouldn't use this expression at all. Whether & where any object is "created" on the executing computing at runtime is entirely up to the compiler, based on its decision-making process during compilation, and sometimes cannot be usefully predicted ahead of time.

There is no hard-and-fast rule that your compiled program will contain instructions to put all temporaries in registers, nor is there a hard-and-fast rule that your compiled program will contain instructions to put all temporaries on the call stack.

C++ isn't a one-to-one mapping of source code statements to computer instructions; it's an *abstraction*.

And this applies to non-temporaries as well. If the object doesn't need to actually "exist" in memory somewhere at runtime, then your compiled program may simply skip that step (or "optimize it out"). That's whether it has a name or not. If you ever take the address of the object, though, this becomes problematic, and thus usually does not happen; you cannot take the address of a temporary so that particular constraint doesn't come up there. Perhaps that's why people think of temporaries as being "more optimisable".

But to say that "temporaries go in registers" is just wrong; you're several layers of abstraction too far away for that to make sense as any sort of rule of thumb.

> CPU REGISTERS are variables inside the processor, which therefore are not found at the RAM level

They're still just "memory spaces", like your bits of RAM. I'd recommend you try to avoid confusing yourself by thinking of registers as variables in the sense of programming code.

> Being a CPU register, a variable, it should contain values, thus acting as a temporary object.

Sure, but also the breath that you exhaled onto your monitor at the time of compilation, is a temporary object. That's similarly got nothing to do with "temporary object" in the sense that C++ means it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I know that c ++ being compiled, it is the compiler that decides what to do, and that there is a very high level of abstraction, and therefore it cannot be foreseen what duty will be created.
But the meaning of my question is not this.
I'm not asking what exactly is done, because in fact it is the compiler that decides it.
I am asking for a clarification on the meaning of the terms.

Comment: The term object indicates a variable, being a CPU register already a container, it no longer makes sense that the latter contains a container(the object).
Why do you say that a temporary object is created in a register, when should the contents of the object be in the register?

Comment: @Tony92 The terms describe things that actually happen, not things that (by your own admission) don't happen. "The term object indicates a variable" Wrong, and has nothing to do with storage location (e.g. register), as I've already stated. I really don't think I can help you any more in this format; you need to sit down with your teacher and have a conversation.

Comment: "The term object indicates a variable" Wrong ?
Why wrong ?

I think unfortunately the meaning of my question has not been understood.
It was not a theoretical or practical question, but mostly a clarification on a term whose definition had induced a doubt in me.
Thanks anyway even if we don't understand each other.

Comment: *They're still just "memory spaces", like your bits of RAM* there is a useful distinction to make,though.  Registers don't have addresses, and calling conventions typically don't let optimize away the address of non-trivially-copyable objects across function boundaries.  (i.e. non-trivially-copyable means it can't be passed or returned in registers.)  So things aren't totally disconnected.  [Why can a T\* be passed in register, but a unique\_ptr cannot?](//stackoverflow.com/q/58339165) is a real case of inefficiency caused by this.

Comment: @Tony92: All variables are objects, but not all objects are variables.  e.g. an object might exist in some storage you allocated with `new`, and only be *pointed to* by pointer variables.  e.g. `int *p = new int;` declares an object of type `int*`, and it points at an object of type `int` that's otherwise anonymous.

Comment: @PeterCordes No but they're connected by being irrelevant to the notion of objects in C++

Comment: This question is basically about *how* real implementations choose to map C++ to asm.  I disagree that it's irrelevant to what the OP is asking about.  But I agree that the OP sitting down with their teacher to talk things out would probably be more useful than going back and forth with misunderstandings in comments.

Comment: @PeterCordes I disagree - the term "temporary object" comes from C++ and the OP has a misunderstanding that there is some mapping to "_how_ real implementations" do things. There is not. Of course I concede that there are constraints (such as those which you have mentioned) due to the properties of various kinds of object in C++ but that's about it. I interpret the question as requiring a point-of-view adjustment in the OP's brain to stop thinking in terms of implementation details _at all_ and just focus on writing in their abstraction, though this is entirely usual here sadly! Ah well

Comment: It is not a problem for me if something is not as I thought, I posted the question for this.
Except that unfortunately in the answer it has been reiterated that the compiler could do what it wants being the abstract C ++ and therefore the single lines of code do not correspond one by one with what the compiler does.
But I already knew this, and it had nothing to do with the question, so I said that perhaps because of the English through which we communicate on the forum, perhaps it can be difficult to express the doubt well. Thanks anyway for the help.

Comment: @Tony92 Good luck!

Comment: I don't think answering an `[assembly]` question with "stop thinking about assembly" is very useful or interesting.  If you want to learn more about assembly language, and how code compiles, @Tony92, look at real compiler output.  e.g. [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](//stackoverflow.com/q/38552116).  And/or read more about calling conventions / ABIs.

Comment: I never asked this.
I Use Compiler Explorer to see what happens when a c++ code is written.

Comment: @PeterCordes Frame challenge is on-topic when the premise of the question is flawed. I know that you love to show off your assembly/architecture knowledge, because it's a bit of a niche and not many other people have such knowledge, and don't worry we all think you're clever, but that doesn't mean it's always the answer. The question is also tagged [tag:object] and [tag:variable]. Clearly, we should not just rely on the OP's choice of tags to decide what domain the question falls under. Either way, this will not be of any further use to the OP (as we agreed a while ago) so, have a great day!

Comment: @LightnessRacesBY-SA3.0: That's fair, I agree the OP is mixing up high and low level concepts, not *just* asking about how objects are passed and returned in practice.  I guess I mostly looked at the parts of the question that made sense as an asm question and answered that (using normal terminology to describe how asm implements C++), but ignoring some of the nonsensical parts.  On second thought, addressing and correcting the nonsensical parts is important, too.

Answer (score 0):

In C/C++, `register int foo` can be an object without an address.  (You can't take the address of a `register` variable in C, allowing even primitive compilers to keep it in a register; optimizing compilers can do this for any variable whose address isn't taken, or for other vars between loads and stores that might alias them).

Return-value objects for trivially-copyable types are like that when they're small enough for a calling convention to return in a register or pair of registers.

(In C++, copy-constructors and destructors for non-trivially-copyable types *do* see the address of return-value objects, which is why most calling conventions won't return such types in registers.)

> do I mean to say that the register is acting as a temporary object, or that the object is created in the register?

The object (e.g. an `int` or `int*`) is *stored in* the register.

Every object has an "object representation", a bundle of bits in some format that represent its value.  That is normally stored at the object's address, but could instead be stored in a register temporarily, or for the object's entire lifetime.

Comment: In C++ `register` doesn't prevent you from taking address of a variable.

Comment: ok but taking an example, the function returns an int.
Now surely the value will be returned in a register, the stack is unlikely to be used in this case.
So does it make sense to consider the register in which the value was returned, a temporary object?

Comment: @Tony92 I would say that the object is *stored in* the register. Otherwise yes.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by object?

Comment: @Tony92: every variable and anonymous temporary in C and C++ is an object, including primitive types like `int`.